# How can I loop through a DataFrame and build a new one (with conditions)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

So I created a DataFrame for my question:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
median = random.uniform(0, 1)
data = [[random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)], [random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)]]
df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A","B"])
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
          A         B         
0  0.243965  0.363859
1  0.376634  0.968781 
2  0.113388  0.555450
```

What I'm trying to do is to look if the value in column A row 0 is greater than the median which was defined earlier. If that's the case I want to apply a certain formula in column B row 0 and save the result in a new DataFrame. If that's not the case I want to apply on the value in column B row 0 a different Formula and also save it in a new DataFrame. I want to repeat this for every row.

Let's say the median equals to 0.3
The two formulas to make it simple are:

x -0.1 and X+0.1

I tried to solve it like this:

```py
for column in df[["A"]]:
    if A > median:
        new_Dataframe = B - 0.1
    else:
        new_Dataframe = B + 0.1
```

The result should look like this and it should be a new DataFrame:

```
   new_DataFrame         
0  0.463859
1  0.868781 
2  0.655450
```

I have problems accessing the wished cells and I have no clue how to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated. Also, the real DataFrame has a lot more rows so I can't just calculate it for every row as I did in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
new_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(np.where(df['A']>median,df['B']-0.1,df['B']+0.1),columns=['new_dataframe'])
print(new_dataframe)

   new_dataframe
0       0.463859
1       0.868781
2       0.655450
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked the way you showed. I have a further question which is how can I leave the index like in my first DataFrame? Because in the original DataFrame my Index is the name of different Equities. When I run the np.where-function the index of the new DataFrame is no longer the name ot the Equity now it is just a number. Do you know how I can fix this?